# Change Id of MVC Radiobuttonfor or trigger jQuery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, radiobuttonfor

Using the following notation in a MVC Radiobuttonfor helper I can create a radio which will have a default button selected if a value exists in the model.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Username, "Y", Model.Username == "Y" ? new { Checked = "checked", id = "YUserName" } : null) No: 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Username, "N", Model.Username == "N" ? new { Checked = "checked" } : null)
```

However the `id = "YUserName"` is not applied to the radio button with the value of "Y"

If I do not have the evaluation expression in the radiobuttonfor helper I can change the id of the radio with the value "Y" i.e.:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.UsePriorFinancialInfo, "Y", new { id = "YUsePriorFinancialInfo" }) 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.UsePriorFinancialInfo, "N")
```

Is there a way to apply a custom Id to one of the radio buttons with the evaluation expression?  If not is there a way I can trigger a jQuery function if either radio button is selected? - Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, remove `Checked = "checked"`. The `RadioButtonFor` helper will assign the value of `checked`. This works fine for me

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Username, "Y", Model.Username == "Y" ? new { id = "YUserName" } : null) Yes:
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Username, "N") No:
```

and rendered the following html

```
<input checked="checked" id="YUserName" name="Username" type="radio" value="Y">
<span>Yes</span>
<input id="Username" name="Username" type="radio" value="N">
<span>No</span>
```

Are you sure the value of property `Username` is set to "Y"?

Comment: Stephen - You are correct the custom id (YUserName) will be set if that input is checked. I wanted to change the id regardless of whether or not an input was checked. I know the id is only set when checked because the html attribute is specified after the question mark, however I cannot find a way to specify the attribute before the question mark.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what your trying to achieve.

Comment: I need to have unique Ids for each radio button in a collection in order to attach a jQuery function to only one instance of the radio button.  However as noted in this article [link]http://goodcoffeegoodcode.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-htmlradiobutton-generates.html the MVC radiobuttonfor helper applies the same Id to all buttons of a radio button collection. As the linked article suggests I can override this behavior by applying `new {@id = ""}` but this prevents me from assigning a default selection for the radio button collection.

Comment: Is the jquery function applied to the selected radio button? If so you could use the `:checked` selector, or if you know the order you could use `.eq()`. In any case you should remove the `new { Checked = "checked" ..` bit and let the helper set this for you based on the value of `UserName`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I worked around the issue by applying a class and attaching my jQuery function to the class. This issue has been resolved.